# All my AMP pages have "Alternate page with proper canonical tag" error

Tags: google-search-console, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

My site has 30k canonical tag errors in google search console and all of them are like the below links is my AMP pages. Should I ignore them? Does it have a negative effect on the site's SEO? is there a way to fix this error?

.../amp/

..../amp/?mode=grid

I think that I can use the noindex tag or anything similar, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I ignore them?

No, thhere is a reason google tells you that something is not right

> Does it have a negative effect on the site's SEO?

Yes. Google See 2 or more pages with the same content. And doesnt know what is the right or wrong one.
At worst it will exclude both pages because It thinks you want to boost your site (Black SEO).

> is there a way to fix this error?

Yes you can put a canonical meta tag to your page. Here an example:

**[www.yoursite.com/blogentry](http://www.yoursite.com/blogentry)**

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.yoursite.com/blogentry" />
```

**[www.yoursite.com/amp/blogentry](http://www.yoursite.com/amp/blogentry)**

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.yoursite.com/blogentry" />
```

So when the google bot will index both pages.
It will see that the AMP Page is technical the same page as the first one.

When you show different content with a query parameter like `?mode=grid` this parameter should also be included, so google sees the following pages as different ones

- [www.yoursite.com/blogentry](http://www.yoursite.com/blogentry)
- [www.yoursite.com/blogentry?mode=grid](http://www.yoursite.com/blogentry?mode=grid)

If you want to learn more about Canonical and what the Best Practices are, look at Google docs:

- [What is canonicalization](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/canonicalization)
- [How to specify a canonical with rel="canonical"](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/consolidate-duplicate-urls)